# XtraReports Printing orientation issue in Devexpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to print a XtraReport in portrait mode.

```
report.PrintingSystem.PageSettings.Landscape = false;
```

But  it is printing in landscape mode automatically,  Please help me on this

Comment: Did you try  xtraReport.Landscape=true; ?

Comment: Yes, but same result

Comment: Change Paper kind to landscape at Design time.

Comment: Have you tried Page Settings => Landscape = True at design mode? AFAIK, `PaperKind` property used to set paper size (e.g. A4, letter, etc.)

Comment: No @TetsuyaYamamoto, you can select  for example A4 Landscaped from PaperKind

Comment: I checked `PaperKind` enum values and found `A4Rotated`, which probably fits what you said "landscaped" (297 x 210 mm).

Comment: My Paper size is 8.5x3.5 (inches), And I am printing it using Epson dot matrix printer